# uninstalling nginx?

Tags: ubuntu, nginx, ubuntu-12.04

I've gone pretty badly wrong and I want to just uninstall and then reinstall a fresh copy to start over.

I've tried

```
#sudo apt-get nginx uninstall
```

that didn't work as well as

```
cd /usr/local/src
wget http://nginxcp.com/nginxadmin2.3-stable.tar
tar xf nginxadmin2.3-stable.tar
cd publicnginx
./nginxinstaller uninstall
```

with no luck, can someone help me out please?
running ubuntu 12.04 server edition, long time support

Answer (score 17, accepted):

To get rid of everything nginx related (configs etc.) do:

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx
```

Answer (score 9):

Uninstall nginx including dependent package

---

Check the Status and version

```
sudo service nginx status
nginx -v
```

First Stop nginx service

```
sudo service nginx stop
```

Removes all but config files.

```
sudo apt-get remove nginx nginx-common
```

*Removes everything.*

```
sudo apt-get autoremove
```

Remove dependencies used by nginx which are no longer required.

```
sudo service nginx status
```

Answer (score 8):

I have tried this and its working

First Stop nginx service

sudo service nginx stop

sudo apt-get purge nginx

sudo apt-get autoremove

Answer (score 7):

Completly away with a wildcard

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx*
```

Answer (score 4):

On ubuntu

```
sudo apt-get purge nginx nginx-common
```